# Git is very slow on OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, git

Whenever I use anything Git related on my MacBook (brand-new Macbook Pro with El Capitan), it takes almost a full minute for each command. I did a simple

```
GIT_TRACE=1 git stash
```

and got back this:

```
17:04:27.460826 git.c:557               trace: exec: 'git-stash'
17:04:27.463136 run-command.c:347       trace: run_command: 'git-stash'
17:04:32.503827 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-dir'
17:04:34.521223 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--show-toplevel'
17:04:35.527473 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-colorbool' 'color.interactive'
17:04:36.534443 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-color' 'color.interactive.help' 'red bold'
17:04:37.538357 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-color' '' 'reset'
17:04:38.544472 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'update-index' '-q' '--refresh'
17:04:39.567521 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'diff-index' '--quiet' '--cached' 'HEAD' '--ignore-submodules' '--'
17:04:40.578480 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'diff-files' '--quiet' '--ignore-submodules'
17:04:41.595078 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'update-index' '-q' '--refresh'
17:04:42.612776 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'diff-index' '--quiet' '--cached' 'HEAD' '--ignore-submodules' '--'
17:04:43.621067 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'diff-files' '--quiet' '--ignore-submodules'
17:04:44.636720 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--verify' 'HEAD'
17:04:45.642275 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'rev-list' '--oneline' '-n' '1' 'HEAD' '--'
17:04:46.648038 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'symbolic-ref' '-q' 'HEAD'
17:04:47.653633 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'write-tree'
17:04:48.664282 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'commit-tree' '<hex_number>' '-p' '<hex_number>'
17:04:49.672125 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'read-tree' '--index-output=/Users/<USER>/.git/index.stash.62412' '-m' '<hex_number>'
17:04:50.707740 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'diff' '--name-only' '-z' 'HEAD' '--'
17:04:51.737890 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'update-index' '-z' '--add' '--remove' '--stdin'
17:04:52.752634 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'write-tree'
17:04:53.772245 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'commit-tree' '<hex_number>' '-p' '<hex_number>' '-p' '<hex_number>'
17:04:54.778991 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'update-ref' '-m' 'WIP on <branch>: <hex_number> <branch> Kept working for a bit' 'refs/stash' '<hex_number>'
Saved working directory and index state WIP on <branch>: <hex_number> <branch> Kept working for a bit
17:04:55.787801 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'reset' '--hard'
HEAD is now at <hex_number> <branch> Kept working for a bit
```

I'm primarily using Atlassian's SourceTree, but the problem also persists on the git command-line (also, so is the log I showed). Our source for hosting the code is *multiple* paid, private repos on GitHub.

Is there anything that I can try to speed up git operations? It doesn't seem to matter which operation it is, they are *all* slow.

I was told to ask this question here as opposed to Stack Overflow.

Comment: [Don't cross-post your questions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927403/git-is-very-slow-on-mac-osx) If you think your question would be better here, request migration by flagging for a moderator.

Answer (score 2):

Run `git gc` once a while to speed up things (if you haven't set it to be automatically on)

Comment: I've tried this, it hasn't helped. In fact, I'm writing this now as git is 'stashing' something....

Comment: This helped dramatically for me. `time git log—one-line -n10` reported 1.5 seconds before. After, it is taking 0.23 seconds. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the answer to this was to disable my WebRoot software. Once that was turned off, git IMMEDIATELY sped up to expected speed.