# Why is git so slow on El Capitan

Tags: macos, git

Rebases and stashes are noticeably, painfully slow. This doesn't seem to happen with the outdated version of git installed by xcode - but the macports version and the version installed from git-scm.com (v2.10.1) run like molasses.

I've seen a few places (including [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217681/git-is-very-slow-on-os-x)) state that WebRoot is the problem, but I am not running it.

Has anyone else experienced this? Has anyone got a solution or at least tips for troubleshooting?

Thanks!

Comment: How much slower is the `brew` build compared to the Apple built `git`? How large are the files involved?

Comment: I just ran `time git rebase origin/master` with the macports git and got "1.77s user 5.25s system 121% cpu 5.782 total". Note that my current branch is already based on master, so this command didn't effect the graph at all.

Then I ran `time /usr/bin/git rebase origin/master` and got "0.05s user 1.61s system 424% cpu 0.392 total".

Comment: Oh, and the entire repo folder is 5.1GB